# Problemas con Repor Writer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows10

Lo que detallo a continuación es un problema que tengo con el `Report Writer (RW)`, si alguno de ustedes les ha ocurrido o saben algo al respecto, les agradeceré la información:

El control (RW) había desaparecido de mi entorno (Visual Studio 2017 en Windows 10 64 bits), y después de mucha investigación y comprobaciones conseguí recuperarlo, pero ahora aun cuando puedo usarlo no funciona correctamente y los informes creados anteriormente me lanzan un error al tratar de abrirlos en diseño:

> "A]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer no puede ser enviado
>   a[B]Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer. El tipo A se origina en
>   'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd808080cc91' en el contexto 'LoadNeither' en la
>   ubicación
>   'C:\Users\MGilT;AppDataLocal\Microsoft\VisualStudio;15.0_458337b8\ProjectAssemblies\6hfzq-mn01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'.
>
> El tipo B se origina en 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms,
>   Version=15.0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd808080cc91' en el contexto 'LoadNeither' en la
>   ubicación
>   'C:\Users\MGilT;AppDataLocal\Microsoft\VisualStudio;15.0_458337b8\ProjectAssemblies\o5xoz7kc01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'.
>   "

La variable `reportViewer1` no se ha declarado o no se ha asignado nunca.

Este error no le encuentro sentido, ya que existe la referencia, la dll del WR para winform existe, incluso llegué a desintalar y reinstalar visual studio en mis intentos por recuperar el control.

Si alguno de ustedes les ha pasado y lo han resuelto, les agradecería la información y ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes duplicado el dll: **Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll** tienes que eliminar el que

> 'C:\Users\MGilT;AppDataLocal\Microsoft\VisualStudio;15.0_458337b8\ProjectAssemblies\o5xoz7kc01\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll'

al parecer el ddl esta duplicado y por eso hay conflicto en el diseñador, me paso lo mismo, pero me puse analizar la execepción que arrojaba y solucione el error eliminando el dll duplicado.